# How to install ubuntu by erasing Red Hat?

Tags: system-installation

I am a newbie here and I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 Desktop on my college machine which already has dual boot of Red Hat and Windows 7. I want to erase both the existing OS and install just Ubuntu. I am installing it from a DVD that I burnt from the iso image obtained from Ubuntu official site after the 700 MB download.

I am using an USB DVD drive and after pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> I am selecting USB-CDROM for booting. But still the Red Hat version is starting and I can't install Ubuntu. I checked on the other laptop and the disk is burnt correctly as well as the drive is working fine. Don't know whats the problem.

Comment: Can you actually boot a "try out" Ubuntu from this DVD on your other machine? May booting from DVD be disabled on your college machines?

Comment: nope its not.. anyways I am trying to update my bios now

Answer (score 0):

If the drive and disk itself are in working order, which they are since you have tried them on the other PC, then the problem lies in the boot options of the target PC.

Looks like the BIOS and the external DVD drive do not like each other. Try upgrading your BIOS (flashing), or another boot media like USB flash memory.

Search the Internet for answers in regards to your PC (motherboard) make and model - **this is not a Ubuntu related problem.**

Start [here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=unable%20to%20boot%20from%20external%20usb%20dvd)

Comment: Please come back and let us know what happened.

Comment: Looks like the problem was with the new RAM that I had upgraded. Just removed the extra RAM from its slot and that did the trick. Must be the problem of frequency matching I guess.

Comment: Glad you resolved your issue. Looks like it wasn't Ubuntu related like i suggested in answer. I'm guessing vote up is in order ;)

Comment: sorry but I don't have the experience points that I can vote up.. I am a complete newbie.. once I reach 15 I will definitely do that.. thanks :)